# PHP: Split string into 2 after length 700 and . (period)

Tags: php

I cant seem to figure the best approach to a PHP problem. I want to accomplish the following

1. I get a string that is, ie. 1000 characters in lenght
2. I want to split a string into 2.
3. The first string need to be 600 characters based on the following condition:
   a) String should only be split if after a period
4. The second section of the string can be the remainder.

I know how to check the length of a string `strlen($string)` and I know how to explode a string into substrings using ie. `explode()`. However, I am not sure how to bring everything together.

Comment: If the period comes after say 100 th position ? you want to split ?

Comment: period refers to what??? explain it a little more

Comment: Your title says 700 chars but your question says 600. Which is it? Also, for clarification: should the string be split at all if a period does not occur until after the 600 (or 700) characters? Or should the string be split no matter what, either at the 600/700 character mark, or at the period if it doesn't come until later in the string?

Comment: It would be fine if period comes after 100th. Doesnt matter how many chars at this point. I just want to split given a lenght, but only after the end of the paragraph. To simply things, I would simply opt for a (.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used, its works.. you have try this...

```
<?php
        $app_title="HIOX INDIA.COM, a leading business web hosting company, is

   currently involved in web services, software/application development, web content 

   development, web hosting, domain registration, internet solutions and web design.";

        echo "<br>Before :".$app_title;
        $length=100; 
        if(strlen($app_title) > $length) { 
        $app_title1 = substr($app_title, 0,strpos($app_title, ' ', $length));}
        $app_title2=split ( $app_title1 , $app_title);
        echo "<br><br>After1 :".$app_title1;
        echo "<br><br>After2 :".$app_title2[1];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use substr() to yank out everything after 600 chars from the original string.
2. Do a strpos() on that resulting sub-string to find the first `.`
3. Use the pos + 600 to do a substr on the original string and use that position as your split point.

Answer (score 0):

Using [substr()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) you can get part of a string defining a initial position and the lenght of the substring. For example:

Getting the first 600 characters:

```
$first = substr ( $input , 0 , 600 );
```

Getting the remaining:

```
$second = substr ( $input , 600 );
```